# use ubuntu **rename** command for folders

Tags: ubuntu, rename, bulk

I want to use the **rename** command to change the names of multiple folders, not files.
I need an example of how to rename
\test 1\
\test 2\
\test 3\
to 
\1\
\2\
\3\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
rename 's/test\ (.*)/$1/' *
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `seq 1 3`; do mv test$i $i ; done
```

an example

```
$ mkdir test1
$ mkdir test2
$ mkdir test3
$ for i in `seq 1 3`; do mv test$i $i ; done                                                                            
$ ls -l 1 2 3
1:
total 0

2:
total 0

3:
total 0
$ rmdir 1 2 3
```

with a space in the directory name

```
$ mkdir "test 3"                                                                                                        
$ mkdir "test 2"                                                                                                        
$ mkdir "test 1"                                                                                                        
$ for i in `seq 1 3`; do mv 'test '$i $i ; done                                                                         
$ ls -l 1 2 3
1:
total 0

2:
total 0

3:
total 0
$ rmdir 1 2 3
```

Comment: no good, I get this error:
mv: target ‘1’ is not a directory
mv: target ‘2’ is not a directory
mv: target ‘3’ is not a directory

Comment: edited with an example, without a space, and with a space in the directory name.